# What is the best approach to redirect Users to login page instead of home in Laravel 10?

Tags: laravel, laravel-10

I'm trying to figure out the best way to redirect a user to the login page instead of the dashboard immediately after they complete their registration in `Laravel 10`. After the user fills in the registration details, they should simply be redirected to the Login page. I tried a couple of methods which never worked including editing the `RedirectIfAuthenticated` middleware. I changed the `return` statement in the `foreach` loop to `redirect('/login')`. Like so

```
class RedirectIfAuthenticated
{
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next, string ...$guards): Response
    {
        $guards = empty($guards) ? [null] : $guards;

        foreach ($guards as $guard) {
            if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
                return redirect('/login');
            }
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

But it still did not work. Any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Laravel Breeze, have you considered modifying the `RegisteredUserController.php` ?

It ends up by these 2 steps :

```php
Auth::login($user);

return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
```

You should probably remove the `Auth::login($user);` and replace the `RouteServiceProvider::HOME` by `/login` ?

Comment: I'm not using Laravel breeze though, I used laravel/ui.

Comment: I think that the idea still the same: 
You probably published the `RegisterController` and you can edit the register method provided by the `RegistersUsers` trait?

Comment: Ok I located the `RegistersUsers` trait but the register method was a bit different. However I modified the register method to have this `return redirect()->route('login')` and it seems to be working now.  Thank you.